# svelte kit serve files in a directory as static files

Tags: sveltekit, sveltekit-adapter-node

I need to serve some files in a directory as static files in the Svelte kit. these files are created in runtime (e.g. user uploaded files).
Is there any Svelte kit built-in way to serve these files? or I should use external packages like [serve-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static)?

these files do not exist in compile time and the `src/lib/assets` or `static/` directory is unsuitable.

```js
// src/routes/media/[...path]/+server.js

export const GET = async ({ params, request }) => {
  const { path } = params;
  if (isFileForbiden(path)) {
    throw error(404);
  }
  // serve static files from '__media_root__/{path}
  return serve(path);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to read the file and return the buffer with `Response`.

`src/routes/media/[...path]/+server.js`

```js
import path from 'node:path'
import fs from 'node:fs/promises'
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit'
import { MEDIA_ROOT } from '$env/static/private'
import { isFileForbiden } from './isFileForbiden'

export const GET = async ({ params }) => {
    const pathName = path.resolve(MEDIA_ROOT , params.path)

    if (isFileForbiden(pathName)) throw error(403) // use 403 (forbiden) here
  
    try {
        const file = await fs.readFile(pathName)
        return new Response(file)
    } catch {
        throw error(404) // use 404 (not found) here
    }
}
```

e.g `.env`

```
MEDIA_ROOT="./media"
```